# MySQL Request to sort by common values

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a small SQL query problem.

Let me explain what I would do.

I have a membership table that I would sort by number of hashtags in common between two members.

This is to create a list of suggestions for a dating site .

In my first table " member" I use " idmem ."

In the second " hashtags " I have the following columns: " idhash ", " idmem ", " hashtags ."

Currently I am making this request.

```
SELECT m.*, 
       nbhash.nb
  FROM member AS m
             INNER JOIN
               (SELECT count(*) AS nb, 
                       mh.idmem 
                  FROM hashtags AS h 
                           INNER JOIN hashtags AS mh 
                              ON h.hashtags = mh.hashtags 
                 WHERE h.idmem = '3016') nbhash
 WHERE m.idmem != '3016'
   AND m.sexe = 'female'
   AND m.orientsexe = 'male'
   AND nbhash.idmem = m.idmem
```

```html
member table

idmem | pseudo   | sexe   | orientsexe |
3016  | jhon     | male   | female     |
3017  | laura    | female | male       |
3018  | david    | male   | male       |
3019  | jessica  | female | male       |
3020  | clara    | female | female     |
3021  | isabelle | female | male       |
3022  | melanie  | female | male       |
3023  | fred     | male   | female     |

hashtags table

idhash | idmem | hashtags
1      | 3016  | basketball
2      | 3016  | cinema
3      | 3017  | basketball
4      | 3017  | cinema
5      | 3019  | basketball
6      | 3020  | cinema
7      | 3021  | basketball
8      | 3021  | football
```

i want to see in this order :

Laura (3017), Isabelle (3021), Jessica (3019), Melanie (3022)

Because Laura and Jhon (me) having 2 same hashtags, isabelle and me 1 same hashtag ......
And i want to see Melanie even if she haven't any hashtag !

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: How to order by member with same hashtags values ?

Comment: Could you post a small data sample and from that sample the desired result that you seek?

Comment: Sorry for mistakes it's my first post on stackoverflow ! ^^

Comment: Sure wait a moment plz

Comment: i hope it's more explicit

Answer (score 1):

I think you must need an `order by` and `left join`:

```
SELECT m.*,  coalesce(nbhash.nb, 0)
FROM member m LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) AS nb,  mh.idmem 
      FROM hashtags h INNER JOIN
           hashtags mh 
           ON h.hashtags = mh.hashtags 
      WHERE h.idmem = '3016'
     ) nbhash
     ON nbhash.idmem = m.idmem 
WHERE m.idmem <> '3016' AND m.sexe = 'female' AND m.orientsexe = 'male'
ORDER BY coalesce(nbhash.nb, 0) DESC
```

Comment: When i try your request, mysql show me in a tab the values coalesce(nbhash.nb,0) and only the first member get 8 although she got only 2 same hashtags :/

Comment: @WhyJ . . . That could happen if there are duplicates in the `hashtags` table.  Try doing `count(distinct mh.hashtag)` rather than `count(*)`.

Comment: Thank you but now only the id 3177 say '4' or he get only '2' and the id 3017 who has one same hastags say '0'  AND when i add "AND mh.idmem != '3016'" after ON h.hashtags = mh.hashtags the result say '2' for id 3177 (that's correct now) but already 0 to the id 3017 ! and when i add "AND mh.idmem = '3016'" 3177 say nothing, but now, the 3017 say '1' (and that's correct) !